# Converting Snowflake Database Timezone

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a database that the timestamps are all in UTC format, but I need to convert, for just this one database, it over to CST for any (and all) timestamp fields.

There are 200 tables, so I don't have each table/field mapped that need to be updated. Is there a way to do this, without using
'''
convert_timezone
''' or
'''
dateadd
'''
on every query written?

The database instance is set to CST, but that database is in UTC.

Comment: why not just use TIMEZONE_NTZ (the dafault) and then leave all the values "as UTC" that's what we did for 5 years. When coverting to other timezones use the 3 parameter version `CONVERT_TIMEZONE( 'UTC' , <target_tz> , <source_timestamp_ntz> )`

Comment: Right now, for every query we write, we then have to use convert_timezone(CST, [timestamp field]) to be able to do joins (and segment sales to the right time period).

I'm trying to avoid having to do that for every query, but that may be easiest to do.

Comment: If all data is UTC there shouldn’t be convertion to join. But i agree the aggregate to “days” you will need to project to someones day. And the someone most likely is not utc. The question then becomes will you ever have a second someone, ot is CST the only perspective that matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a stored proc that would read the ACCOUNT_USAGE.COLUMNS table, identify columns that have a date datatype and then construct SQL statements for each table that updated the values using CONVERT_TIMEZONE

Comment: I've got a list of all the fields that have timestamp now for that database. For the SQL statements, are we just running alter statements to use convert_timezone('America/Chicago', [insert field here]) or something else?

Comment: No - I'm suggesting you physically need to convert the values in each column to the new timezone e.g. UPDATE TABLEA SET COL1 = convert_timezone('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York', COL1)